# Take screenshot of current showing screen, NOT the current activity

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm trying to make a little Android app that triggers a screenshot capture of the current showing screen when a specific notification appears. For example, I'm on whatsapp and a Whatsapp notification appears -> That triggers a whatsapp capture.

Well, my current code actually detects notifications and triggers a screenshot when a notification comes, but not the way I want. I get a screenshot of my MainActivity, even if it's not showing on the screen. I just want to screenshot what it's appearing on the screen. It seems easy but I'm not being able to do it!

I leave my current NotificationReceiver class, which is failing because it captures the MainActivity and not the screen:

```
class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String temp = intent.getStringExtra("notification_event") + "\n" + txtView.getText();
        txtView.setText(temp);

        if (intent.getStringExtra("notification_event").contains("bet")) {
            Log.i("Dentro", "dentro");

            Date now = new Date();
            android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

            try {
                // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
                String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

                // create bitmap screen capture
                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                int quality = 100;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
                Log.i("Catch","Error dentro del if(contains)");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//fin if
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how can I proceed? I'm actually stuck. Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use [the media projection APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) on Android 5.0+, and set your `minSdkVersion` to 21. For privacy and security reasons, apps cannot take screenshots of other apps without explicit user permission, and that only became possible with Android 5.0.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter) demonstrates taking screenshots on demand.